# How to Display text in Middle of table cell Horizontally and vertically in html css?

Tags: html, css

Any way to middle value in my table cell, both horizontally and vertically.

Here is code:

```
<table>
    <tr style="display: block;height: 44px !important;color:#fff;">
        <td style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;"><span class="" ><img src="../images/cal/green-25.png" alt="green-food" width="32px" height="32px"/> <label style="" class="ylw ">Yellow</label></span></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;">200 Cal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display: block;height: 44px !important;color:#fff;">
        <td style=""><span class="" ><img src="../images/cal/green-25.png" alt="green-food" width="32px" height="32px"/> <label style="" class="ylw ">Yellow</label></span></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;">200 Cal</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: FYI don't use `display:table-cell` for `td`s!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak : thanks friend but when i remove it also not norking

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Better use `display:table-cell` for `td`s (useless, since its the default value) than `display: block` for `<tr>`s, breaking all table layout.

Comment: @iDevTechnolab You should read [Separation of presentation and content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content). Inline styles should be avoided, specially if you repeat them for each element.

Comment: @Oriol Thanks! i din't know that! But `<tr>`s seems to be `table-row` by default instead of `block`

Comment: You should also remove the `display: block` inline style of of your `<tr>` tags.  Along with removing your inline style declaration `display: table-cell` for your `<td>` tags as mentioned above by @Dhaval Marthak.  Then just add these two declarations to your `<td>` tags: `text-align: center` and `vertical-align: middle`.  The first will align horizontally and the second vertically in the middle of the cell.

Comment: yes i remove all other formating .. that all are not necessory and updated with display -table-cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the few changes to your markup and added CSS [Removed `disaply:table-cell` from all `td`]

```
img,label{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**Fiddle Exmaple**](http://jsfiddle.net/3XzKk/)

*Side Note:* Don't use `display:table-cell` when you're already dealing with the table cells which is `td` itself. `table-cell` can be applied for `div`s according to need.

Comment: it works now fine i am updating with all our instruction

Comment: @iDevTechnolab Don't forget to mark answer as accepted as it can be useful to other community members :)

Comment: Ok Thanks keep helping :) /